# How to convert an array reference to an numpy array python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a class `Boundary` which has an attribute `points` which is an numpy array.

```
class Boundary():
   self.points = np.array([])
   ...
```

And class `Spline` is a child class of `boundary`.

But when I call `spline.points`, I can't get an numpy array.
When print it, I saw it is an object, so how can I convert points to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of yours sets attribute `self.points` instead of assigning `points` as attribute.
See the following example

```
class Boundary():
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = np.arange(3)

a = Boundary()
print(a.points)
print(type(a))
print(type(a.points))
```

Output is

```
[0 1 2]
<class '__main__.Boundary'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**EDIT**:

The following code using childs:

```
import numpy as np


class Boundary():
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = np.array([])

    def setPoints(self, points):
        self.points = points


class Spline(Boundary):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


points = np.arange(5)
spline = Spline()
spline.setPoints(points)
print(spline.points)
```

Corresponding output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: `class Boundary():
           def __init__(self):
                  self.points = np.array([])

           def setPoints(self, points):
                   self.points = points #points is an numpy array
  ....

 class Spline(Boundary):
         def __init__(self):
             super().__init__()

    ....

    spline = Spline() 
    spline.setPoints(points)
`
When I call `spline.points[k]`. It said "too many indices""